# Unable to add elements using the setAttribute

Tags: vue.js

I am using the VUE JS code and trying to add the `setAttribute` to some of the tags.

Here is the code I am using **:**

```
changetab() {
      const demoClasses = document.querySelectorAll(".delCon__select");
      demoClasses.forEach(button => {
        button.setAttribute("tabindex", "0");
      });
      return true;
    },
```

but when I view in the code inspector, It does not show added to it, I have added the above function in computed.

template is like this **:**

```
<template>
  <el-container class="orders"></el-download>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make this type of request in [Vue's Lifecycles](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html), like: `created` or `mounted`.

Something like:

```
mounted() {
  this.changetab()
}
```

[Computed](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) would not be the most appropriate place for this type of action.